# Nutch Elasticsearch indexer plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch, indexwriter

I have many urls in nutch seed.txt file,  http://www.foodurl1.com,http://www.foofurl2.com etc..
and want to index all URL in ES under single index e.g. foodindex and each url as separate type e.g foodindex/foodurl1, foodindex/foodurl2. So i can search each url individually based on type. Is there any out of the box way to pass 
type in elasticindexwriter.java  in ES indexer plugin(by default its using "doc" type).

or any other suggestion to achieve this requirement.